# Laptop to desktop memory RAM adapter reliability

Tags: memory, hardware, compatibility, ram

I have recently came across an adaptor that would allow me to use laptop memory on my desktop. See item below:
http://www.amazon.co.uk/Laptop-Desktop-Adapter-Connector-Converter/dp/B009N7XX4Q/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1382361582&sr=8-1&keywords=Laptop+to+desktop+memory

Both the desktop and the laptop use DDR3. 
My question is, are this adapters reliable? 
I have 8 GB available and I was wondering if they could be put to use in my gaming rig. 
The desktop is an i7 machine generally used for gaming and some basic development.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The adapter should be reliable based on how it looks. There is not much to it only that it extends the "mini" RAM block to a bigger one. You can make the analog with A-B USB cables.

What you should also consider is if both RAM devices use the same frequency and possible heat issues as you will have to cool down the laptop memory more that if it was desktop size. This is because a lot of current goes trough smaller size compared to the desktop based RAM blocks. Then again you have the extension board to handle and disperse some of the heat so if you are not having some really extensive RAM operations you should be fine but you should check what is the working frequency on both of them. For example if the laptop one is faster than the maximum one your computer can support then you won't get that faster performance and the RAM block will work with the frequency of the system bus but if it is slower then the system bus will work on that frequency.

Answer (score 0):

Use standard things on this module as reference to calculate the width. Measure it on image and scale to a reference item and check on your system. Use contacts or the lock in grooves to do the scaling since they are of standard dimensions on all modules. Or the module length...